# Magento - Buy it now buttons and checkout process

Tags: php, magento, google-checkout

Hey everyone!  I was hoping to start using Magento for a very simple checkout landing page.  I have a few questions regarding the capabilities of Magento:

1) I don't actually want to use the 'add to cart' button but rather a 'buy it now' button.  So when a user clicks to purchase a product it automatically takes you to the checkout process.  Does anyone know if this is possible to configure with Magento?

2) If I purchase an SSL certificate from somewhere like verisign.com can I keep users on my domain through the check out process?  I'd also be willing to use something such as Google Checkout if it were possible to customize the look of the Google skin to match my site.

3) Is Google Check out like PayPal in that I transfer money from Google Checkout to a designated bank account?

Thanks all.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1.)  Yes, it is possible.  You could write a module to observe an event (perhaps checkout_cart_product_add_after) and automatically re-route the user to the checkout page.

2.)  The SSL doesn't matter when it comes to keeping someone on your site.  (If you checkout users on your site, you will need an SSL).  The kicker is what payment gateway you utilize.  Some payment gateways will require the user to enter payment information through a different domain than your own.

3.)  As for how Google checkout works, I'm not sure.  I have never known anyone to actually use it.  Most people I know just use authorize.net.  I'm sure you can easily find more information just by Googling it.